# Conjecture based on an integer sequence from R.P. Stanley

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

OEIS sequence A067855 gives the sum of squares of a vector of coefficients of $s_\mu$, $\mu\vdash 2n$, produced by summing the expansion of $s_\lambda^2$ over all partitions $\lambda\vdash n$. It appears to have a simple generating function.
Conjecture:
replacing $s_\lambda^2$ by $s_\lambda s_{\lambda´}$ results in the same sequence. This is not trivial since the vector of coefficients is different. It just 'magically' gives the same length squared.
Is it trivial to prove this?

Comment: What is \lambda' ? I try to guess something like conjugate partition, but not sure...

Comment: @Max : yes, $\lambda´$ is the conjugate or transpose partition of $\lambda$